# vscode-python - Can I use the data viewer's filters to apply 'greater-than' and 'less-than' filters simultaneously?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

For the [vscode-python plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python), I am using the 'data viewer' to explore a large array of data from a `CSV` file.

The data viewer has a 'filters' tool (see picture), which can be used to (1) find matches in a column for specific values (e.g. `1996`) and (2) find values 'greater than' or 'less than' a particular value (e.g. `>2006` or `<2014`).  However, for my case, I would like the filters tool to filter for values 'greater-than' *and* 'less-than' at once (e.g. `>2006 AND <2014`).

Is this possible?

I found this [announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-april-2019-release/) of the introduction of the data viewer, but was unable to find any detail explaining options for the data viewer's filters.

Also, if there is documentation explaining possible input for the data viewer's filters, please let me know. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in VS Code, it supports single condition filtering, but it does not support  "`>2006 AND <2014`".

So I have submitted this problem and you could follow it: [Can the "data viewer" in VS Code filter data with multiple conditions?](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5560)

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature does not appear to exist as of April 2021.

It has been over a week since Jill Cheng [submitted a github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5560) asking the vscode-jupyter team about this question, and there has been no response, so I would imply that the feature does not exist.

Also, given that vscode-jupyter currently has `971` open issues, I would venture to guess that this feature is not exactly a top priority.